# Architecture to develop multiple emails for every thread

Tags: email, architecture, notifications

I am working on an ERP solution that will have a separate microservice to handle notifications and emails. My vision is to have threads to understand who is subscribed to the thread and send all the subscribers relevant notifications when an event occurs. Every time a ticket is raised or a service request is made a thread is created to track comments on the ticket. They also receive notifications on the tickets through emails. But the challenge is when I receive an email notification and reply to that notification we want to create a comment on the thread and notify all the thread subscribers.

Our understanding is we need to create a custom email address for every thread and process all the messages sent to that email address. How do we create these huge numbers of email addresses? Do we have to modify our MX records since we are currently using GSuite? I see many sites have similar setups there must be a technical name for this architecture

At this point, I am not sure what is the technical name for a service like this.